# wordpress admin sort users by custom post type amount

Tags: wordpress, admin, custom-post-type

Can anyone help me out? 
I have a custom post type in my wordpress theme called real estate and I am trying to add it to my admin dashboard in the users tab so I can follow how many posts each user has and then sort the users list by highest and lowest.

I have seen some scripts but none of them have been working so wanted to start fresh.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: post your php file where you have added add_action method for implement admin side manager for you page. and implement action with register_post_type http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Answer (score 0):

You can get the idea on how to implement this by reading

http://j3webworks.com/blog/wordpress-how-to-sort-different-custom-columns-of-a-custom-post-type